# Converting sub JSON string to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I would like to convert the output below to pd.DataFrame but it does not work. The output shows that the most important data are still in one field named `data.quotes`. Any help would be appreciated.

THE CODE:

```
 url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/ohlcv/historical'
parameters = {
 'symbol':'BTC',
 'time_start':'2019-04-01',
 'count':'90',
 'interval':'daily',
 'convert':'JPY'
}
headers = {
'Accepts': 'application/json',
'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
}
session = Session()
session.headers.update(headers)
response = session.get(url, params=parameters)
data = json.loads(response.text)
data = json_normalize(data)
```

THE OUTPUT:

```
                                                                 0
 data.id                                                               1
 data.name                                                       Bitcoin
 data.quotes           [{'time_open': '2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z', 'ti...
 data.symbol                                                         BTC
 status.credit_count                                                   1
 status.elapsed                                                      194
 status.error_code                                                     0
 status.error_message                                               None
 status.timestamp                               2019-06-06T03:06:18.538Z
```

`data.quotes` structure:

```
 [{'time_open': '2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z', 'time_close': '2019-04-02T23:59:59.999Z', 'quote': {'JPY': {'open': 462700.4901095795, 'high': 546074.4289677355, 'low': 462522.0664843293, 'close': 543171.8812680268, 'volume': 2372545999849.8755, 'market_cap': 9570973713180.293, 'timestamp': '2019-04-02T23:59:06.000Z'}}}, 
  {'time_open': '2019-04-03T00:00:00.000Z', 'time_close': '2019-04-03T23:59:59.999Z', 'quote': {'JPY': {'open': 543684.9195633918, 'high': 591262.8246796157, 'low': 543313.1581902393, 'close': 554053.3118729277, 'volume': 2551318140998.9854, 'market_cap': 9765833431708.75, 'timestamp': '2019-04-03T23:59:03.000Z'}}}
```

EXPECTED DATAFRAME:

```
open               high                low               close             volume             market_cap          timestamp
462700.490109579   546074.428967735    462522.066484329  543171.881268026  2372545999849.87   9570973713180.29   2019-04-02T23:59:06.000Z
```

Comment: What is your expected output dataframe? Should the fields other than data.quote be included or not?

Comment: @GZ0 I added a sample of the expected output for the first row from `data.quotes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the info out of the dict, then put the info in dataframe.
use the code below.

```py
import json
import pandas as pd
from requests import Session

url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/ohlcv/historical'
parameters = {
    'symbol':'BTC',
    'time_start':'2019-04-01',
    'count':'90',
    'interval':'daily',
    'convert':'JPY'
}
headers = {
    'Accepts': 'application/json',
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
}
session = Session()
session.headers.update(headers)
response = session.get(url, params=parameters)
data = json.loads(response.text)

# take out the info
used_list = [
    item['quote']['JPY']
    for item in  data['data']['quotes']
]

# put the info into dataframe
dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_records(used_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should fulfill your need.

```
...
data = json.loads(response.text)
df = json_normalize(data["data"]["quotes"])
df.drop(columns=["time_open", "time_close"], inplace=True)
df.columns = [s[len("quotes.JPY"):] for s in df.columns]
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
```